# Want to Add checkbox in all direction of Image Slider

Tags: css, html

Below is the Slider I am working on. But I am facing some problem with Fog caption Alignment.
I wanted to align the Html caption in all four direction ie:

1. Will be **top left**
2. Will be on **top right**
3. Will be on **bottom left**
4. etc..

I want to place checkbox with some text in these fields.So please let me know how to proceed.
I tried doing but it struck in right side only.

http://codepen.io/lleger/pen/aeowD

Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about why the sliding effect messes up behind the white box?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of what you want. I updated your code. Please see the link:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmHhC

Is that what you want?

Comment: I think he's referring to the transition effect being messed up behind the box, although the question is unclear.

Comment: @Tamura-Your caption is fine.But I want the same caption in left side aswell atleast.
ie Html Caption in left and right both Side with text and checkboxs.

Comment: @AkashPathak: I'm sorry I still don't understand. The left side of what? Can you draw a figure regarding where you want to put your caption?

Comment: @Tamura-The caption box u fixed is fine.But I want another like-http://s10.postimg.org/pq0qj3xx5/Screenshot_from_2014_04_04_16_10_47.png.Such that In slider screen there will be 2 or more caption boxes.One will be in right and another in left.Thanks